# How to find the member_id value needed for custom header X-Dropbox-Perform-As-Member

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm developing a dropbox app (accessing a Dropbox for Business account). I need to pass along a custom header, X-Dropbox-Perform-As-Member, which has it's value set to a member ID (or member_id).

For the life of me I can't seem to figure out where to find or retrieve this specific value. Hell, I don't even know what it looks like ...

Anyone care to point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few places the member ID might come from... it depends a lot on the kind of app you're building. One likely source is a call to [`/members/list`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/business/docs#members-list). Another likely source is [`/members/get_info`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/business/docs#members-get-info) (if you're looking up by email address).

For an auditing app that's watching activity within a Dropbox for Business account, you'll find the `member_id` as a member of lots of events in the audit log (i.e. via [`/log/get_events`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/business/docs#log-get-events)).